# why can't I run this exe file from the command prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line-interface

My file's path is `D:\installed software\Wing IDE 3.2\bin\wingide.exe`.

Now I want to run the `wingide.exe` file on the command line. So first, I enter `cmd` to the startup box, then get `C:\Documents and settings\Administrator>`

Then I typed `d:` then `installed software\Wing IDE 3.2\bin\wingide.exe` after it. and click the enter key. It shows `D:\installed is not an command`. Why? How can I correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows command prompt (I hope you are not actually using MS-DOS!) does not care about what keys you've typed. It cares about the command you are attempting to run and it seems it's this:

```
installed software\Wing IDE 3.2\bin\wingide.exe
```

So you are asking to run program "installed" and pass three parameters to it:

- software\Wing
- IDE
- 3.2\bin\wingide.exe

... because that's how most command prompts work: you use white space to separate items. You probably want this:

```
"installed software\Wing IDE 3.2\bin\wingide.exe"
```

or:

```
"D:\installed software\Wing IDE 3.2\bin\wingide.exe"
```

Answer (score 2):

Your path has a space in it so you need to put quotes around it. Try typing:

```
"D:\installed software\Wing IDE 3.2\bin\wingide.exe"
```

Answer (score 2):

Type:

```
"D:\installed software\Wing IDE 3.2\bin\wingide.exe"
```